# "That's the reason why she spoke" & "That's the reason she did so"

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english

Here are the two sentences.

> *"That's the reason why she spoke"*  
>   *"That's the reason she did so."*

Which one sounds natural to native speakers?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It depends on the context and what was said immediately before it. Normally i find 'noun did so' less common overall though

Comment: Both are entirely different. The former one talks about why did she speak like that and the second one talks about why did she do ***anything.*** The question would have been better with the second sentence being ... *That's the reason she spoke so...*

Comment: @Maulik, EyeOfTheHawks: I would say it makes no significant difference whether ***why*** is present in either of OP's examples, which are therefore both fine.

Comment: @FumbleFingers both are fine on their own way. I was concerned about deciding upon only one thing - did she speak in both the cases or did she *do* something. Let her do **one** thing and talk it in different ways to understand the question better. I'm not concerned about the rest of the sentence structure but was peculiar about whether she spoke or did something! :)

Comment: @Maulik: Yeah, I understand the distinction you're making. I'm just saying the presence or absence of ***why*** in *either* of the examples makes no difference to their meanings. In the second example, ***so*** (which could always be replaced by ***it, that,*** etc.) refers to some unspecified preceding action (whether she *spoke, sneezed, committed suicide*, or whatever is unknowable without context). FWIW, I personally don't really think they're both "fine" - I won't say including both ***the reason*** and ***why*** is "wrong", but I think it's at the very least "clumsy".

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/235125/50720 may help.

Answer (score 2):

This issue was [covered on ELU long ago](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37639/). There is a school of thought which claims there's [something inherently "wrong"](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/37648/2637) with conjoining ***reason*** and ***why*** in this way, but in practice most native speakers are either unaware or don't care about such pedantry.

I can't think of any specific context where you *can't* omit ***why*** after ***reason*** used as a noun meaning *cause*. Nor do I think it ever makes any significant difference to the *meaning* - it's just a stylistic choice.

Because of the "pedantic" position linked to above, you might want to avoid using ***the reason why*** yourself (it's never *necessary*). But don't assume just because someone else *does* use it, their English is "poor" (though I would say it's more a *spoken* than a careful formal written usage).